# How to check multiple tables existence in mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

I use Entity Framework and mysql and I must use raw SQL (FromSQL).

I'm going to union the tables but I must know if each exists in the database, because it must exist for the union table. I want to check all tables by name and pick the existing tables and union them.

I think I should use multiple queries for each table's to know their existence.

```
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_01'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_02'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_03'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_04'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_05'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_06'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_07'
Show Table Like 'Log_2018_01_08'
```

And I will store it in the

```
List<string> ExistTables;
```

And then I will write union SQL with the ExistTable List and for loop.

```
string sql = "";
for(var i in ExistTables)
{
    sql += //union tables which are in exist table list.
}
```

Is this a good way?

If possible I want to get existing tables for only 1 query.

Comment: I would interrogate information_schema.tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = '<Your table name>'
```

Comment: Thank you but how should i have multiple check for this one query? Like a... query multiple name but only get exist table or etc? If it can't, then i must query multiple.

Comment: If you can make array of all table then you can apply this query using for loop.

Answer (score 0):

What Gajjar Parth said, but if you don't have permission to query the metadata then try

```
select count(*) from <tablename>
```

for each of the tables and then proceed accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for anser my question. But is there have any way to query only 1 times?

Comment: I would do this in a stored procedure although you could try an equivalent batch file as dynamic SQL if you can't do stored procs for some reason.

Comment: Try this:

    INSERT <lExistTables> SELECT <table_name> FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME IN ("<table1>", "table2",...)'